# What is the reason for the error message '/hostfxr.dll is either not designed to run on Windows is it contains and error'?

Tags: windows, powershell

I just opened a PowerShell console on Windows 11, and after running any command, it showed a dialog with a message like:

> /hostfxr.dll is either not designed to run on Windows is it contains and error

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just download the last hostfxr.dll from [this website](https://www.dll-files.com/hostfxr.dll.html) and copy it to this directory:

> C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7